# Print a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, printing

I'm trying to print a bidimensional array in c++ but I have a problem. I followed the traditional way to print a vector `vectorName.size()` inside a for loop. So the way that I follow was this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

void impMat(vector < vector <int> >, vector < vector <int> >);

int main () {
    vector < vector <int> > A;
    vector < vector <int> > B;
    vector <int> temp;

    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
          temp.push_back(i);
       }
       A.push_back(temp);
       B.push_back(temp);
    }

    impMat(A,B);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

void impMat(vector < vector <int> > A,vector < vector <int> > B) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < A[i].size(); j++){
          cout << A[i][j] << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < B.size(); i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < B[i].size(); j++){
          cout << B[i][j] << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
}
```

But that's print something like this

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
```

Expected output

```
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
```

How do I could get to print correctly my vectors?

Comment: What is the desired output? And why did you omit the actual code that prints? That seems like the part that's probably the problem

Comment: Off-topic: Range based for loops might be more convenient in given case.

Comment: I don't see how you achieve line breaking for some of the cases - normally, one would add a `std::cout << std::endl;` *after* the inner loop.

Comment: What is `A`, what is `B`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Be aware that `sizeof(std::vector)` will *always* return the same size, no matter if it is empty or filled with 7, 1012, 1M values! The `sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)` pattern only applies for raw arrays and only as long as these have not decayed to pointers!

Comment: `sizeof(B[i])/sizeof(int)` -- Why are you doing this?  A `vector` knows the number of elements it has by using the `size()` member function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because using size prints the wrong output

Comment: Are your vectors correctly filled? How are they initialised? Please create an [mcve] (emphasis on 'complete' here...).

Comment: @EnriqueAlvarez *because using size prints the wrong output* -- Well, that attempt is wrong.  It does not do what you believe it does.  A vector never gets `size()` wrong.  If you see `3` printed, that means the vector has `3` elements.  It isn't telling you a lie.

Comment: Also since `impMat()` doesn't modify the vectors they should be passed as `const&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem basically is how you fill your vectors:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
          temp.push_back(i);
     }
     A.push_back(temp);
     B.push_back(temp);
     // now temp yet contains all the values entered, so you produce:
     // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 in first loop run,
     // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 in second,
     // ...
     // most simple fix:
     temp.clear();
}
```

More efficient, though, as you want to have the same data anyway:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     temp.push_back(i);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
     A.push_back(temp);
     B.push_back(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two simple ways of printg `std::vector`s of `std::vector`s:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo{
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    };

    // range-based for-loops:
    for (auto const &row : foo) {
        for (auto const &col : row) {
            std::cout << col << ' ';
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }

    std::cout.put('\n');

    // ordinary for-loops:
    for (std::size_t row{}; row < foo.size(); ++row) {
        for (std::size_t col{}; col < foo[row].size(); ++col) {
            std::cout << foo[row][col] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
}
```